# Bucket Sort Implementation

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, bucket-sort

I have to implement a bucket sort so that it sorts an array with `size = 100` with randomly generated numbers between 0 and 100. My buckets are as follows:

```
Bucket0: (0<=x<10)
Bucket1: (10<=x<20)
.
.
.
Bucket9: (90<=x<100)
```

Now I understand the theory behind the bucket sort, where I insert the elements into each individual bucket, but what I don't get it how to actually create the buckets. Do I create an array say `B` with the buckets being arrays themselves? Or is the a more standard way of implementing a bucket sort with integers?

I just need a nudge in the right direction, thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to show your effort to solve this problem. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: Which variation of [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) are you supposed to use for this assignment?

Comment: It was never specified, all it said was to sort each bucket with an insertion sort. I was actually able to get the initial array into a 2D array with each row being the "bucket" now I just have to figure out how to do an insertion sort on each row

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
You have to declare another array (we can say b) with length 101. The length represents and range of our numbers.

Now you have to over the first array and for each cell, and when you find every number k (0 <= k <= 100) , you have to ++ the b[k]. Something like: `b[a[i]]++;`
 
 Now we have array `b` which represents how many times each number `k` appeared in the first array. We can override the first array:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= RANGE; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < b[i]; j++)
        a[p++] = i;
```

While on your case, RANGE is 100.
Complexity: O(n)

Notice that we can implement that with one variable instead of using an array, which is doing the same thing, but every time for a different number.
Not saves much but saves a little Complexity of space.

Comment: That's a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#Variant_algorithms) , which could be considered as one of the variations of [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) . The OP didn't state which variation of bucket sort is to be used.